# need to convert a htaccess file to php.ini

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am moving a website from 1 host to another but this new host is configured differently and the htaccess password doesn't work. They have informed me that the settings need to be done via php.ini rather than htaccess.

Quoting part of the hosts message: "errors include attempting to use php_value directives in your .htaccess file, which will not work as we run PHP as CGI"

I am not very well versed with these files, i have included my htaccess file below and wondered if someone could explain which bits are incorrect? URL has been replaced.

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Better website experience for IE users
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force the latest IE version, in various cases when it may fall back to IE7 mode
#  github.com/rails/rails/commit/123eb25#commitcomment-118920
# Use ChromeFrame if it's installed for a better experience for the poor IE folk

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
    # mod_headers can't match by content-type, but we don't want to send this header on *everything*...
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|xml|oga|ogg|m4a|ogv|mp4|m4v|webm|svg|svgz|eot|ttf|otf|woff|ico|webp|appcache|manifest|htc|crx|xpi|safariextz|vcf)$" >
      Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

#  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
#  </IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(svg|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proper MIME type for all files
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------


# JavaScript
#   Normalize to standard type (it's sniffed in IE anyways) 
#   tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
AddType application/javascript         js

# Audio
AddType audio/ogg                      oga ogg
AddType audio/mp4                      m4a

# Video
AddType video/ogg                      ogv
AddType video/mp4                      mp4 m4v
AddType video/webm                     webm

# SVG.
#   Required for svg webfonts on iPad
#   twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
AddType     image/svg+xml              svg svgz 
AddEncoding gzip                       svgz

# Webfonts                             
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf    ttf ttc
AddType font/opentype                  otf
AddType application/x-font-woff        woff

# Assorted types                                      
AddType image/x-icon                   ico
AddType image/webp                     webp
AddType text/cache-manifest            appcache manifest
AddType text/x-component               htc
AddType application/x-chrome-extension crx
AddType application/x-xpinstall        xpi
AddType application/octet-stream       safariextz
AddType text/x-vcard                   vcf


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Gzip compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

# Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# HTML, TXT, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, HTC:
<IfModule filter_module>
  FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
  FilterChain     COMPRESS
  FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_filter.c>
  # Legacy versions of Apache
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
</IfModule>
</IfModule>




<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html 
  ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
  ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

# Feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType application/atom+xml      "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week" 

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files  (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType font/truetype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>



<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

FileETag None

Options -MultiViews 

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .js .xml .json .rss .atom

Options -Indexes

<IfModule php5_module>
    php_value session.cookie_httponly true
    php_flag short_open_tag on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/$1 [R=302,L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess these bits are causing trouble

```
<IfModule php5_module>
php_value session.cookie_httponly true
php_flag short_open_tag on
</IfModule>
```

Try removing them and see if the error goes away.  If it does this is the bit, if not you ahve some more to set.

If that is the issue , then find a way to set these in your app specific php.ini or in your code.